# postgres role to access all schema

Tags: postgresql, role

I am using postgres 9.4 database with many schemas. How can I create a login role that can select  table of  all table of all schema and also any new schema that we create in the database

Comment: `create role spiderman superuser login;` BTW in any case you will should to explicitly specify the schema name like `select * from shchema.table` for every schemes except of default.

Comment: Thanks. My database is AWS RDS and I do not have superuser. Got "ERROR:  must be superuser to create superusers". So , do I need to manually  give USAGE to schema and SELECT ON ALL tables to  have access to all existing schema? Could I use 'ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ' to give access to furture schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your comment I think this statement will work:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
FOR ROLE role_name
IN SCHEMA public
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO role_name;
```